# CheckID does not have associated TTL

Tags: c#, .net, consul

I'm trying to utilize Consul .NET API to register and fire health checks via TTL. First I'm registering my service with following code:

```cs
var address = node.Address;
var id = ServiceId(address);
var registration = new AgentServiceRegistration
{
    ID = id,
    Name = node.ClusterName,
    Address = node.Address.Host,
    Port = node.Address.Port.Value,
    Check = new AgentServiceCheck
    {
        TTL = settings.AliveInterval, // 10sec
        DeregisterCriticalServiceAfter = settings.AliveTimeout, // 60sec
    }
};    
// first, try to deregister service, if it has been registered previously
await consul.Agent.ServiceDeregister(registration.ID);
await consul.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration);
```

Right afterwards, I'm trying to fire a TTL via:

```cs
await consul.Agent.PassTTL("service:" + ServiceId(addr), string.Empty);
```

However, what I end up with is an exception thrown during PassTTL: **Consul.ConsulRequestException: Unexpected response, status code InternalServerError: CheckID "service:{service-id}" does not have associated TTL**

And the related log from consul agent itself:

> [ERR] http: Request PUT /v1/agent/check/pass/service:{service-id}, error: CheckID "service:{service-id}" does not have associated TTL from=127.0.0.1:25419

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm using `consul agent -dev` (version: 1.0.1) and Nuget package Consul (version: 0.7.2.3).

Answer (score 3):

Turns out `AgentServiceRegistration.Check` property is pretty useless. I've achieved the expected result with `CheckRegister` method.

Here's the code

```cs
var registration = new AgentServiceRegistration
{
    ID = "serviceId",
    Name = node.ClusterName,
    Address = node.Address.Host,
    Port = node.Address.Port.Value
};    
// first, try to deregister service, if it has been registered previously
await consul.Agent.ServiceDeregister(registration.ID);
await consul.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration);
await consul.Agent.CheckRegister(new AgentCheckRegistration()
{
    ID = "checkId",
    Name = "Check Name",
    Status = HealthStatus.Passing,
    TTL = settings.AliveInterval,
    ServiceID = "serviceId",
    DeregisterCriticalServiceAfter = settings.AliveTimeout, // 60sec
})
```

Now you can pass TTL via

```cs
await consul.Agent.PassTTL("checkId", string.Empty);
```

Just be sure to deregister your check afterwards

Answer (score 2):

It looks like my example was missing a crucial detail here: a `ServiceId(address)` method was constructing a service ID in form of *protocol://service@host:port/* which resulted in Consul complaining about lack of TTL. Changing it to *service@host:port* seems to fix the error.

I guess in this case a consul error message was very misleading.

Comment: Yes, the error message is misleading. I faced a similar error, and your post indirectly helped me to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if id format is:

```
"service:{service id}:{number}"
```

In your case, you must pass:

```
"service:" + ServiceId(addr) + ":1"
```

as your check id.

Comment: What the {number} stands for?